# Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^2}{n^2 - z^2 }$ converges uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I'm trying to show that the serie $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^2}{n^2 - z^2 }$ converge uniformly over all compact subsets of $B(0,1)$. If we take a compact $K\subset B(0,1)$ for all $z\in K$ we have $|z|<1$. Note that $\left| \frac{z^2}{n^2-z^2}\right| < \frac{1}{n^2-{|z|}^2}$. I need to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2-{|z|}^2}$ converges for use the M Weierstrass test.

Comment: Since $|z|<1$, $n^2-|z|^2>n^2/2$ for $n\leq 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists $r<1$ such that $|z| \leq r$ for all $z \in K$. Hence $|\frac {z^{2}} {n^{2}-z^{2}}| \leq \frac 1 {n^{2}-r^{2}} \leq \frac 2 {n^{2}}$ for $n >\sqrt 2 r$. [First few terms do not have an effect on unform convergence].